# What is wrong with my RVEST code that I am getting HTTP Error 404?

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to use RVEST to webscrape multiple pages on a websites (Audible.com). For some reason it isn't working, and I don't know if there's something wrong with my code? I just am adapting from a tutorial so not sure how to do everything right.

Code will be below in full.

I also used the 'safely' adverb to see if it would tell me what the error is and this is what I got:

$result
[1] "This page could not be accessed"

$error
NULL

Code:

```
library(rvest) # Web scraping
library(tidyverse) # Data wrangling
library(RCurl)

audible <- read_html("https://www.audible.com/search")
```

```
# first selecting one book cover to get the right CSS
audible %>%
  html_nodes('#product-list-a11y-skiplink-target > span > ul > div > li:nth-child(1) > div > div.bc-col-responsive.bc-spacing-top-none.bc-col-8 > div > div.bc-col-responsive.bc-col-6 > div > div > span > ul > li:nth-child(1) > h3 > a')%>%
  html_text()

# then removing " :nth-child" texts to select all book covers, not just one, and storing as 'titles'
titles <- audible %>%
  html_nodes('#product-list-a11y-skiplink-target > span > ul > div > li > div > div.bc-col-responsive.bc-spacing-top-none.bc-col-8 > div > div.bc-col-responsive.bc-col-6 > div > div > span > ul > li > h3 > a')%>%
  html_text()
```

Functional so far, but then I try to adapt that for all pages not just 1:

```
# function to scrape links and names for given full_url
w.scrape <- function(full_url, rule){
  
  # status
  print(paste("w.scrape processing", full_url))

  # get titles
  the_titles <- read_html(full_url) %>%
    html_nodes( rule ) %>% 
    html_text()
  
  # get links
  the_links <- read_html(full_url) %>%
    html_nodes( rule ) %>% 
    html_attr('href')
  
  # as a dataframe
  df <- data.frame("titles" = the_titles, "links" = the_links,
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 
  
  return ( df )
}

# return the urls of the next pages
w.tree <- function(rel_url){
  
  root = "https://www.audible.com/search"
  
  full_url <- paste0(root, rel_url)

  # see if there's a next page link
  last_link <- read_html( full_url ) %>% 
             html_node("#pagination-a11y-skiplink-target > div > div.bc-col-responsive.bc-text-right.bc-col-8 > div > span > ul > li:last-child(3) > a") %>% # the 'next page' link is the last link in this div
             html_text()
  
  
  if(c("next page", "previous page") %in% last_link){
    
      # not last page
      if(last_link == "next page"){
    
      next.page <- read_html( full_url ) %>% 
        html_node("#pagination-a11y-skiplink-target > div > div.bc-col-responsive.bc-text-right.bc-col-8 > div > span > ul > li:last-child(3) > a") %>% # the 'next page' link is the last link in this div
        html_attr('href')

      w.tree(next.page) # recurse (calling w.tree() inside w.tree() )
    
      return(next.page)
    }
  
    # # last page
    # if(to.continue == "previous page"){
    # 
    #   return(full_url) # no child to crawl
    # 
    # }
  }
}

# convenience function to make a list of urls and their text from wikipedia category pages
w.list <- function(rel_url, rule){
  
  root = "https://www.audible.com/search"

  to.scrape <- c(rel_url, w.tree( rel_url ) ) # not tested beyond 2 pages
  
  #print(paste("To Scrape:", to.scrape)) # status
  
  output <- data.frame() # container
  
  for(page in to.scrape){
    output <- rbind( w.scrape( paste0(root, page), rule ), output )
    Sys.sleep(0.5) # pause 1/2 second before scraping the next page*
  }
  
  return(unique(output)) # return unique rows
  
}
```

**The next section is what gives me trouble:**

```
child_rule = "#pagination-a11y-skiplink-target > div > div.bc-col-responsive.bc-text-right.bc-col-8 > div > span > ul > li a"

# let's see how it works
all_books <- w.list(rel_url = "https://www.audible.com/search",
                               rule = child_rule )

all_books
```

I have no idea if I put the right code into "child_rule" though.

I added a safely adverb to try to learn something (as per http://ritsokiguess.site/docs/2017/09/07/safely-possibly/) and got this:

```
# then using safely to see what
w.list=safely(w.list)
map(audible,w.list)
```

**My code is adapted from Part 1 of this RVEST Tutorial: https://github.com/turnerdan/rvest_tutorial**

Thank you very much for any ideas on why this is going wrong or how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the adaptation you have made of the code is not entirely correct.

If you want to go through all the results pages, you can do:

```
for (i in 1:60) {
   audible <- read_html (paste0 ("https://www.audible.com/search?page=", i))
#Your code for each page
}
```